# windows cannot access davwwwroot SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, windows-7, iis-7, sharepoint-2010

we are using SharePoint 2010, the users had some of the document library as map drive in the windows explorer, lately the user getting some error when he try to access this map drive
[image: error1]

also the user tried to open the library using [open with explorer] and still getting the same error
[image: error2]

note that I'm not facing this issue from my PC.
how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The "Explorer View"-style connection to SharePoint uses the WebClient (WebDAV) service on the client computer.

Confirm that this service is running on the user's computer. It may need to be started or restarted.

Comment: I checked it, it was running, I think the problem is related to User profile on the local machine.

Comment: I the user able to navigate to the document library in the web browser on that computer?